# Sinusoidal or other custom move type between two points

Tags: javascript, points

I am trying to build a function that moves bullets in mini game. For the moment i am doing it in very simple way.

Have function to calculate radian angle between two points:

```
this.rftv = (p1, p2) => Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
```

Have to different points and calculate angle between them:

```
var x = objects[this.destination].x,
    y = objects[this.destination].y,
    rad = tools.rftv( { x: this.x, y: this.y }, { x: x, y: y } );
```

Define speed boost:

```
this.attack_speed = 2.5;
```

Move bullet using angle and speed boost:

```
this.x += Math.cos(rad) * this.attack_speed;
this.y += Math.sin(rad) * this.attack_speed;
```

What i am trying to do is to not move bullets in linear way, i am rather trying to move bullets using sinus wave, to achieve something like this:
[image]

I have no idea how to start to build it, maybe someone could help and write a function that would take two points and make object move sinusoidal between them.

Comment: Does the sine wave need to converge at the second point? Are there any restrictions on the frequency or amplitude of the wave? Should we have to assume these are all configurable?

Comment: yes bullet must be dispatched from point A and must go to point B, it would be best if the sine wave was configurable in a way that if 10 bullets are dispatched they have different paths, and you can literaly see them going in different settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add a few more variables to each instance:

```
// initialization

this.distance = 0;
// have a max amplitude of about 30-50 depending on how you want it to look
this.amplitude = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * MAX_AMPLITUDE;
// have a fixed period somewhere between 10-50 depending on how you want it to look
this.period = 30;
this.initial = { x: this.x, y: this.y };

// on each frame

this.distance += this.attack_speed;

this.x = this.initial.x + Math.cos(this.rad) * this.distance;
this.y = this.initial.y + Math.sin(this.rad) * this.distance;

const deviation = Math.sin(this.distance * Math.PI / this.period) * this.amplitude;

this.x += Math.sin(this.rad) * deviation;
this.y -= Math.cos(this.rad) * deviation;
```

Turns out I had a slight error with the math, it's corrected now, along with a very basic demo below.

A positive amplitude should cause the initial trajectory of the bullet to go at an angle slightly counter-clockwise compared to the angle from point A to point B, then oscillate back and forth on the way to B.

```js
class Bullet {
  constructor({initial = {}, destination = {}, amplitude = 50, period = 30, speed = 2.5} = {}) {
    let { x: ix, y: iy } = this.initial = initial;
    let { x: dx, y: dy } = this.destination = destination;
    this.amplitude = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * amplitude;
    this.period = period;
    this.speed = speed;
    
    this.distance = 0;

    this.x = ix;
    this.y = iy;
    
    this.rad = Math.atan2(dy - iy, dx - ix);
  }
  
  update() {
    this.distance += this.speed;
    
    this.x = this.initial.x + Math.cos(this.rad) * this.distance;
    this.y = this.initial.y + Math.sin(this.rad) * this.distance;
    
    const deviation = Math.sin(this.distance * Math.PI / this.period) * this.amplitude;
    
    this.x += Math.sin(this.rad) * deviation;
    this.y -= Math.cos(this.rad) * deviation;
  }
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let initial = {
  x: canvas.width / 4,
  y: canvas.height * 3 / 4
};

let destination = {
  x: canvas.width * 3 / 4,
  y: canvas.height / 4
};

let bullet = new Bullet({initial, destination});

console.log(bullet.amplitude);

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  
  // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  bullet.update();
  
  ctx.fillStyle = '#0000FF';
  ctx.fillRect(bullet.x, bullet.y, 1, 1);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
  ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height * 3 / 4, 1, 1);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00FF00';
  ctx.fillRect(canvas.width *3 / 4, canvas.height / 4, 1, 1);
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: this sir is very nice and good solution, it is working very nicely, i have only one problem now, this is the demo i prepared for simplicity https://jsfiddle.net/map1cmq2/ if i want wider flight of bullet and have set period and amplitude to 200, some bullets (most of them) will miss its target, do you maybe have a fix for that ? ;)

Comment: The amplitude doesn't matter. In order to hit the target, the period must be the result of dividing the euclidian distance between point A and point B by any positive integer number.

Comment: any chance you could show some example function how to calculate that, i am very rusty in math

Comment: demo is working like a charm, i know its probably a problematic question but i am struggling with implementation for 2 hours already, in demo situation its working ok, but when i implemented this into game bullets doesnt seem to start at given `x` and `y` coords, it starts somewhere else i cannot even see them. Maybe you have some idea why it could be happening, i dont have any functions affecting this system.

Comment: ok i have figured out the problem, it was scope problem, now all is working ok, thank You for ton of good work sir